# ¿Como puedo unir estos dos codigos en una placa arduino?

Tags: c, arduino

Quiza la pregunta suena un poco pasada de raya, pero es que no tengo idea de como unirlos. Como dije en otra pregunta referente al arduino, estaba intentando hacer un inicio de sesion que al validar el usuario, me redirija a una pagina simuladora de un FTP (algo por el estilo).

El codigo del inicio de sesion ya lo tengo a mano y es el siguiente:

```
   void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if(bufferSize < 400) header[bufferSize++] = c;


        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {       

          // send a standard http response header
          if(strstr(header, "YXJkdWlubzphZG1pbg==") != NULL) {
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response

            client.println();
            if(strstr(header, "GET / HTTP/1.1")) {
              client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
              client.println("<html>");
              client.println("AQUI TENDRIA QUE MOSTRAR LA PAGINA 'FTP' al validar el usuario");
              client.println("</html>");
            } else {
              client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
              client.println("<html>");
              client.println("some other page");
              client.println("</html>");
            }

          } else {
            // wrong user/pass
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
            //client.println("HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required");
            client.println("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Secure\"");
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println();
            client.println("<html>Denegado</html>"); // really need this for the popup!


          }

          bufferSize = 0;
          StrClear(header, 400);

          break;

        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}


// sets every element of str to 0 (clears array)
void StrClear(char *str, char length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Vi otro codigo en esta fuente [en el que explican como listar archivos con hipervinculos](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/ethfiles.html). Tome el codigo que ofrecian para descargar, lo pobre y funciona perfecto... y es el siguiente:

```
    #include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

/************ ETHERNET STUFF ************/
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 117 };
EthernetServer server(80);

/************ SDCARD STUFF ************/
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;
SdFile file;

// store error strings in flash to save RAM
#define error(s) error_P(PSTR(s))

void error_P(const char* str) {
  PgmPrint("error: ");
  SerialPrintln_P(str);
  if (card.errorCode()) {
    PgmPrint("SD error: ");
    Serial.print(card.errorCode(), HEX);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(card.errorData(), HEX);
  }
  while(1);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  PgmPrint("Free RAM: ");
  Serial.println(FreeRam());  

  // initialize the SD card at SPI_HALF_SPEED to avoid bus errors with
  // breadboards.  use SPI_FULL_SPEED for better performance.
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);                       // set the SS pin as an output (necessary!)
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);                    // but turn off the W5100 chip!

  if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, 4)) error("card.init failed!");

  // initialize a FAT volume
  if (!volume.init(&card)) error("vol.init failed!");

  PgmPrint("Volume is FAT");
  Serial.println(volume.fatType(),DEC);
  Serial.println();

  if (!root.openRoot(&volume)) error("openRoot failed");

  // list file in root with date and size
  PgmPrintln("Files found in root:");
  root.ls(LS_DATE | LS_SIZE);
  Serial.println();

  // Recursive list of all directories
  PgmPrintln("Files found in all dirs:");
  root.ls(LS_R);

  Serial.println();
  PgmPrintln("Done");

  // Debugging complete, we start the server!
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
}

void ListFiles(EthernetClient client, uint8_t flags) {
  // This code is just copied from SdFile.cpp in the SDFat library
  // and tweaked to print to the client output in html!
  dir_t p;

  root.rewind();
  client.println("<ul>");
  while (root.readDir(p) > 0) {
    // done if past last used entry
    if (p.name[0] == DIR_NAME_FREE) break;

    // skip deleted entry and entries for . and  ..
    if (p.name[0] == DIR_NAME_DELETED || p.name[0] == '.') continue;

    // only list subdirectories and files
    if (!DIR_IS_FILE_OR_SUBDIR(&p)) continue;

    // print any indent spaces
    client.print("<li><a href=\"");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      if (p.name[i] == ' ') continue;
      if (i == 8) {
        client.print('.');
      }
      client.print((char)p.name[i]);
    }
    client.print("\">");

    // print file name with possible blank fill
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      if (p.name[i] == ' ') continue;
      if (i == 8) {
        client.print('.');
      }
      client.print((char)p.name[i]);
    }

    client.print("</a>");

    if (DIR_IS_SUBDIR(&p)) {
      client.print('/');
    }

    // print modify date/time if requested
    if (flags & LS_DATE) {
       root.printFatDate(p.lastWriteDate);
       client.print(' ');
       root.printFatTime(p.lastWriteTime);
    }
    // print size if requested
    if (!DIR_IS_SUBDIR(&p) && (flags & LS_SIZE)) {
      client.print(' ');
      client.print(p.fileSize);
    }
    client.println("</li>");
  }
  client.println("</ul>");
}

// How big our line buffer should be. 100 is plenty!
#define BUFSIZ 100

void loop()
{
  char clientline[BUFSIZ];
  int index = 0;

  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean current_line_is_blank = true;

    // reset the input buffer
    index = 0;

    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        // If it isn't a new line, add the character to the buffer
        if (c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
          clientline[index] = c;
          index++;
          // are we too big for the buffer? start tossing out data
          if (index >= BUFSIZ) 
            index = BUFSIZ -1;

          // continue to read more data!
          continue;
        }

        // got a \n or \r new line, which means the string is done
        clientline[index] = 0;

        // Print it out for debugging
        Serial.println(clientline);

        // Look for substring such as a request to get the root file
        if (strstr(clientline, "GET / ") != 0) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();

          // print all the files, use a helper to keep it clean
          client.println("<h2>Files:</h2>");
          ListFiles(client, LS_SIZE);
        } else if (strstr(clientline, "GET /") != 0) {
          // this time no space after the /, so a sub-file!
          char *filename;

          filename = clientline + 5; // look after the "GET /" (5 chars)
          // a little trick, look for the " HTTP/1.1" string and 
          // turn the first character of the substring into a 0 to clear it out.
          (strstr(clientline, " HTTP"))[0] = 0;

          // print the file we want
          Serial.println(filename);

          if (! file.open(&root, filename, O_READ)) {
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println();
            client.println("<h2>File Not Found!</h2>");
            break;
          }

          Serial.println("Opened!");

          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
          client.println();

          int16_t c;
          while ((c = file.read()) > 0) {
              // uncomment the serial to debug (slow!)
              //Serial.print((char)c);
              client.print((char)c);
          }
          file.close();
        } else {
          // everything else is a 404
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();
          client.println("<h2>File Not Found!</h2>");
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

Tiene exactamente lo que busco! y funciona! primero intente creando un archivo HTML con hipervinculos a los archivos de texto que contiene la tarjeta SD. En la computadora por separado funciona, pero al momento de insertarlo a la placa e intentar hacer tal cosa, no me los encuentra. Intente unir estos dos codigos pero me pasan dos cosas:

**1. La direccion IP cambia y el explorador no responde a la peticion.**

**2. La tarjeta SD se corrompe y necesito formatearla para poder volver a hacer ensayos.**

Hasta ahora no he logrado unir ambos codigos... y pido ayuda a ustedes: ¿Como juntar ambos codigos?

Ya sabemos que el lugar donde debo mostrar la lista con los hipervinculos a los archivos es en este bloque del codigo:

```
        client.println();
        if(strstr(header, "GET / HTTP/1.1")) {
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          client.println("AQUI TENDRIA QUE MOSTRAR LA PAGINA 'FTP' al validar el usuario");
          client.println("</html>");
        } else {
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          client.println("some other page");
          client.println("</html>");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero: **ni idea de arduino**, pero *unir* esos códigos no parece que sea *demasiado* complicado.

Los `include`s:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
```

Modificamos tu `setup( )`, para que se encargue también de la SD:

```
void setup( ) {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin( 9600 );

  // initialize the SD card at SPI_HALF_SPEED to avoid bus errors with
  // breadboards.  use SPI_FULL_SPEED for better performance.
  pinMode( 10, OUTPUT );                       // set the SS pin as an output (necessary!)
  digitalWrite( 10, HIGH );                    // but turn off the W5100 chip!

  if( !card.init( SPI_HALF_SPEED, 4 ) ) error( "card.init failed!" );

  // initialize a FAT volume
  if( !volume.init( &card ) ) error( "vol.init failed!" );
  if( !root.openRoot( &volume ) ) error( "openRoot failed" );

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin( mac, ip );
  server.begin( );
  Serial.print( "server is at " );
  Serial.println( Ethernet.localIP( ) );
}
```

Y ahora, en la parte en la que indicas, un ligero cambio:

```
client.println( );
if(strstr( header, "GET / HTTP/1.1" ) ) {
  client.println( "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" );
  client.println( "<html>" );
  ListFiles( client, 0 ); // <- Ponemos esto aquí, para que liste.
  client.println( "</html>" );
} else {
  client.println( "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" );
  client.println( "<html>" );
  client.println( "some other page" );
  client.println( "</html>" );
}
```

El 2º parámetro puede ser `0`, o una combinación de `LS_SIZE` y `LS_DATE`, para que te muestre el tamaño y la fecha de los archivos.

Deberias de copiar, en tu archivo de código, **todo el cuerpo de la función `ListFiles( )`** del ejemplo que tienes:

```
void ListFiles( EthernetClient client, uint8_t flags ) {
  ...
}
```

Una ultima cosa: solo soporta SD en formato `FAT`, así que a ver lo que le metes :-)